# Flex Hero Playbook app fails to minimize

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, blackberry-playbook

I am having an issue with a playbook app I am working on. This is the first one i've done using Flex Burrito Hero, and on the simulator I noticed that the app fails to minimize gracefully (when multi-tasking etc). Are there any resources for handling minimization or anything that could help guide me to debug whats going on with that?

Answer (score 0):

you can swipe up to minimize the application. 
Simulator though hangs some time and may not give the good experience. 
This is known issue.